# How to translate labels on a bundle

Tags: php, symfony, foscommentbundle

I made my own file with the translations of the bundle fields in my own language. It's working on my FOSUserBundle I created another one for comments bundle but not in FOSUserComment. It's on Translation folder.

Exemple code:

```
<button data-url="{{ url("fos_comment_remove_thread_comment", {"id": comment.thread.id, "commentId": comment.id, "value":  constant('FOS\\CommentBundle\\Model\\CommentInterface::STATE_DELETED')}) }}" class="fos_comment_comment_remove">
    {% trans from 'FOSCommentBundle' %}fos_comment_comment_delete{% endtrans %}
</button>
```

Can I replace `{% trans from 'FOSCommentBundle' %}fos_comment_comment_delete{% endtrans %}` to work with my translation file?

The translation works fine with defined languages but i copy a file translation and implement my language cause didn't exist on the bundle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure what you did there. Can you tell where do you store the files and what names you gave to the translation files?

you can also use `{{ 'fos_comment_delete'|trans }}`

Update your question so I can update my answer.

Comment: I just create a file called FOSCommentBundle.ca.yml on folder CommentBundle/Resources/translations. And in my config.yml its defined with 
parameters:
    locale: ca
And inside framework:
translator: { fallbacks: ['%locale%'] }.

Comment: I just remake the file and cleared cache again and now its working thanks.